# How to write test cases for Select Box onChange Method in React Testing Library?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, react-test-renderer, react-testing

I have a Select Box and set the data in a state by the `onChange` event. Please have a look at the below code. Anyone can help me to write cases for this `onChange` event in React Testing Library.

```
const [optionValue, setOptionValue] = useState({ value: '', label: '' })

const handleOnChange = (option: OptionType): void => setOptionValue(option)
```

```
<Select name={title} id={title} placeholder="Choose an Option" options={setOptionsData} defaultOption={optionValue} onChange={e => { handleOnChange(e) }} data-test="options" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using [userEvent](https://testing-library.com/docs/ecosystem-user-event/) which comes as part of the React Testing Library ecosystem. It allows you to write tests which are closer to real user behaviour. Example:**

```
it('should correctly set default option', () => {
  render(<App />)
  expect(screen.getByRole('option', {name: 'Make a choice'}).selected).toBe(true)
})


it('should allow user to change country', () => {
  render(<App />)
  userEvent.selectOptions(
    // Find the select element
    screen.getByRole('combobox'),
    // Find and select the Ireland option
    screen.getByRole('option', {name: 'Ireland'}),
  )
  expect(screen.getByRole('option', {name: 'Ireland'}).selected).toBe(true)
})
```

Have a look at [this article](https://cathalmacdonnacha.com/how-to-test-a-select-element-with-react-testing-library) (which I wrote myself) for more info on how to test select elements using React Testing Library.